# How to find element by class name in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have created code like this:

```
if email_part.get_attribute('class') == "v-MailboxItem-from":
            mail_from = email_part.find_element_by_class_name("v-MailboxItem-from")
            print(mail_from)
```

its returning true however if I want to get item or items with "find_elements_by_class_name" its returning nothing or error that he cant find this selector. Why?

```
<a id="v221" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/Taae3746ae45756e1.M3b10ad8bef3e5df385134a0f?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><span title="<changed>"><changed></span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="<changed>"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span>kolejny mail</span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 6:41 PM (15 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">10&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">opppppppppp</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="<changed>"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a><a id="v222" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:87px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/T5f804dc18d5e61ab.Mce73942086376ab9230dcd22?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><span title="<changed>"><changed></span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="<changed>"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span><changed></span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 5:54 PM (16 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">10&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">asbfvsdf</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="<changed>"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a><a id="v223" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:174px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/T77b60b01579e9c57.Me645d2e05cf797456c8bf942?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><span title="<changed>"><changed></span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="<changed>"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span><changed></span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 5:54 PM (16 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">10&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">abcd</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="<changed>"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a><a id="v224" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:261px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/T225213ef239e45bf.Mb3a1ca0e28f74ead9a0ee853?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" role="presentation" class=" v-Icon i-tick" title="Verified as sent by The Fastmail Team.">
<polyline points="7.13 13.19 10.26 16.25 16.88 7.75"></polyline>
</svg><span title="support@fastmail.com">The Fastmail Team</span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="Enable security, and other features"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span>Enable security, and other features</span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 2:51 PM (19 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">17&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">## Protect your account
When using internet services, you deserve more choices and control.
To get the best experience, we strongly encourage you to set up these account</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="Select (Enable security, and other features)"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a><a id="v225" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:348px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/T07ac74438fef3db3.M965fada2848636a1865c0c7b?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" role="presentation" class=" v-Icon i-tick" title="Verified as sent by The Fastmail Team.">
<polyline points="7.13 13.19 10.26 16.25 16.88 7.75"></polyline>
</svg><span title="support@fastmail.com">The Fastmail Team</span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="Choose your address with a personal domain"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span>Choose your address with a personal domain</span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 2:51 PM (19 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">18&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">## Email from your own domain
Create the online identity you want with your own domain.
Owning a domain lets you send email from an address that matches your website such as</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="Select (Choose your address with a personal domain)"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a><a id="v226" class="v-MailboxItem app-listItem is-read" style="position:absolute;top:435px;left:0px;transform:none;opacity:1;" role="row" href="https://www.fastmail.com/mail/Inbox/T37327541a03fea20.Ma6c1aca0ab56e132a920428e?u=724940d7"><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-from"><span class="v-MailboxItem-name"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" role="presentation" class=" v-Icon i-tick" title="Verified as sent by The Fastmail Team.">
<polyline points="7.13 13.19 10.26 16.25 16.88 7.75"></polyline>
</svg><span title="support@fastmail.com">The Fastmail Team</span></span><span class="u-hidden"></span></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-unread"></div><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-subject u-ellipsis" title="Import your mailbox and calendars"><span class="u-hidden"></span><span>Import your mailbox and calendars</span></div><div class="u-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="u-standardicon v-Icon i-attachment" role="presentation">
<path d="M9.42,13l6.23-6.19c1.13-1.13,2.22-1.2,3-.43.61.61,1.08,1.74-.22,3l-7.94,7.89a3.36,3.36,0,0,1-4.75,0h0a3.33,3.33,0,0,1,0-4.72l6.84-6.8"></path>
</svg></div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-time" title="Wednesday, September 02, 2020 2:51 PM (19 hours ago)">Sep 2</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-size">18&nbsp;KB</div><div role="gridcell" class="v-MailboxItem-preview u-ellipsis">## Welcome! Let's get you up and running
Hi there,
Thank you for signing up! Let's bring in your email, calendars and contacts to your new account.
Use our [import tool](https://www.fastmail.com/settings/setup) or [start our interactive</div><div role="gridcell" class="u-hidden"></div><div role="gridcell" class="app-listItem-box"><input type="checkbox" class="app-listItem-boxInput" title="Select (Import your mailbox and calendars)"></div><div role="gridcell"><button title="Pin important messages to help you quickly find them later." class="app-listItem-pinButton">Pin</button></div></a>
```

Comment: Please produce a minimal example. What website or the structure or the html tags do you want to retrieve.

Comment: Please provide the html element.

Comment: updated, but format is quite bad